# How to requestAccessToEntityType method in Swift 2.0 iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, eventkit

I am trying to set reminder and need to access request to entity type method in Swift 2.0 for iOS9. However, it gives me the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier

```
@IBAction func setReminder(sender: AnyObject) {

    appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
        as? AppDelegate

    if appDelegate!.eventStore == nil {
        appDelegate!.eventStore = EKEventStore()
        appDelegate!.eventStore!.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeReminder, completion: {(granted, error) in    //use of unresolved identifier EKEntityTypeReminder
            if !granted {
                println("Access to store not granted")
                println(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                println("Access granted")
            }
        })
    }

    if (appDelegate!.eventStore != nil) {
        self.createReminder()
    }
}
```

This code works for Swift, but not Swift 2. Did anybody have this type of issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`EKEntityType` is now an `enum`, which contains two types one could specify.

For `EKEntityTypeReminder`:

```
appDelegate!.eventStore!.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Reminder, completion: 
{(granted, error) in
    if !granted 
    {
        println("Access to store not granted")
        println(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    else 
    {
        println("Access granted")
    }
})
```

Or simply just:

```
.Reminder
```